# Creation of new universe after dooms day

Tags: islamic-philosophy, creation

Is there any possibility of creating new universe after dooms day.

What does Islam say about this?

Comment: In Quran Allah refers to himself as “ lord of the worlds” so it does not say world. It is possible there is already different universe and different worlds . Mankind could never expand or reach into even distances within our own universe.

Answer (score 1):

In my knowledge Qur'an does not speak any new creation after day of judgement. Qur'an speaks of a renewed creations, that is raising of the dead from graves, or raising of dead who are cremated. Every one who is dead will be brought to life to take an account of what he has earned(Whether good or evil). Our main concern should be that if we do righteous acts, we will enjoy in the kingdom of God and in his presence. That will be indeed an eternal bliss which no eyes or imaginations can grasp in its reality or totality.

As for the matter of new universe, it is Allah will what he will do after day of judgement, he is involved in new affairs regularly. But his promise is that we shall have heavens or hell. That is for sure, why waste time in thinking about issues which are not helpful for us. Satan is ever close to misguide us, we should seek God's refuge from the irrelevant whispers of Satan.

In my opinion, this creation is indeed the best, as also affirmed in Qu'ran and Hadeeth. 
It is potentially possible that God can actually make more better creation than this one if he wished to create. He wills and It is :)